# Laravel: Accessor to get 'slug' from a polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship

I am wanting to list all comments. Comments have a Polymorphic relationship with Blog, News etc. When listing all the comments I want to convert the commentable_id to the slug I have saved in the Blog/News table.

So far I have:

```
public function getCommentableIdAttribute($value)
{
    // $post_type = $this->commentable_type;
    $post_detail = Blog::find($value);

    return $post_detail['slug'];
}
```

I want to use $post_type and find the value based on that. Naturally though, I am getting a non-object issue if I replace Blog::find() with $post_type->find().

I don't know at this point which table I want to reference.

• Is there a better, more Laravel way of reversing this? The docs seem to suggest that I need to know the Model first.

• If not, any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help.

Comment: There is some misconception in your code I think. But first, you can do: `$commentable = new $this->commentable_type; $commentable->find($value);`. However why would you want to do that if you can instead do this: `$this->commentable->slug;` ?

Comment: Boom. Second option worked perfectly. Thanks for that dexzo - Legend!